# Getting error in retrieving input text from text box to the other form

Tags: c#, textbox

I have a login form "`frmLog()`" which has text box for username and password, now I want to get the input text from username text box. Please see the code below and don't be confuse I am using mysql database so the other syntax code are not important.

This is the Login form "`frmLog()`"

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ApareceCrudLib a = new ApareceCrudLib("localhost", "root", "", "cashieringdb");
            string user = txtLogin.Text;
            string pass = txtPassword.Text;
            string query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE username='" + user + "' AND password=MD5('" + pass + "')";
            int result = a.Count(query);
            if (result == 1)
            {
                frmMain main = new frmMain();
                main.ShowDialog();
                this.Dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login Failed! Try Again");
                txtLogin.Text = "";
                txtPassword.Text = "";
            }
        }
```

This is the other form where I want to retrieve the code "`frmMain()`". Please see the `public void dataLog()` that is the part of code that I attempt to get the input value from `frmLog`.

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    a = new ApareceCrudLib("localhost", "root", "", "cashieringdb");
    loadDataGridView_Main();
    dataLog();
}
public void loadDataGridView_Main()
{
    dgvMain.Rows.Clear();
    List<string>[] detailList = a.mysqlSelect("Select * From sales");
    for (int i = 0; i < detailList.Length; i++)
    {
        dgvMain.Rows.Add(detailList[i][0], detailList[i][1], detailList[i][2], detailList[i][3]);
    }
}
public void dataLog()
{
    frmLog kk = new frmLog();
    txtLog.Text= kk.txtLogin.ToString();
}
```

This is the wrong result

[image]

The result must be the username from `frmLog()` example "client123". What do you think is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kk.txtLogin.ToString()`, returns a string that represents the current object. In this case your current object is `TextBox`.

Instead display the `TextBox`, you should show the `TextBox`'s value.
Change that code to:

`kk.txtLogin.Text;`

**UPDATE**

If you want to display the `txtLogin` value from `frmLog` in `frmMain`, you can declare static variable in `frmLog` that store the `txtLogin` value.

in `frmLog`:

```
public static String LOGIN_USER = "";
```

Then in `button1_Click`:

```
    if (result == 1)
    {
      LOGIN_USER = txtLogin.Text;
      frmMain main = new frmMain();
      main.ShowDialog();
      this.Dispose();
    }
```

in `frmMain_Load`:

```
    public void dataLog()
    {        
       txtLog.Text= frmLog.LOGIN_USER;
    }
```

Comment: I dunno how you do that but I will study your code it works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In your datalog() Methode is the first error.

Replace:`txtLog.Text= kk.txtLogin.ToString();`

With:`txtLog.Text= kk.txtLogin.Text;`

In:

```
 public void dataLog()
 {
        frmLog kk = new frmLog();
        txtLog.Text= kk.txtLogin.ToString();
 }
```

You create a new frmlog object without showing it, so the textbox is empty. You should retrieve the text from the text box after the user input.

Answer (score 0):

It is so because you are trying to read data from a new instance of your `frmLog();`

In you `frmMain`, do not write this :

`frmLog kk = new frmLog();`

instead create a public reference in your form class

`public frmLog kk;`

and then, In your frmLog,

```
frmMain main = new frmMain();
main.kk=this; 
main.ShowDialog();
```

this will create a reference to your first form in second form.